# Can i add more numbers to my field number value in my collection?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to to add numbers to my total price on firebase collection? For example, I have collection called wallet and there is a field called pocketMoney with number. I want to update my pocketMoney with more values.

Sorry for the bad explanation I can explain more.

Comment: add code, what are you trying to do

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agree with the above comments - most importantly though what does *more values* mean. Does it mean you have a value and want to have additional values in an array? e.g. 1 and then you want to make it a list 1, 2, 3.... or do you mean you want to add to the existing value e.g. 1 and you want to increment it by 1 so that value is now 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `FieldValue.increment`, which allows you to increment a value in the database without knowing its current value on the client. For all on this see the documentation on [incrementing a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), which also contains this JavaScript example:

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update({
    population: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50)
});
```